# DDR Treeview Menu display selected root and its child node

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt, treeview, dotnetnuke

I'm working on a DDR Treeview menu for DotNetNuke to display only the selected Root items and its child node to be expanded. Here is what I'm trying to achieve.
(Left vertical menu)
Any advice please?

[image]

This is the xslt code and is currently displaying all root items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:param name="ControlID" />
  <xsl:param name="Options" />
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="root" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:if test="node">
      <ul class="treeview filetree" id="{$ControlID}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node" />
      </ul>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($) {
          $("#<xsl:value-of select="$ControlID" />").treeview(
            <xsl:value-of select="$Options" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
          );
        });
      </script>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="node">
    <li>
      <xsl:if test="node and (@depth != 0 or @breadcrumb = 1)">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">open</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@enabled = 0">
          <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <a href="{@url}">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="@selected=1">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">selected breadcrumb</xsl:attribute>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="@breadcrumb=1">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">breadcrumb</xsl:attribute>
              </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
          </a>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:if test="node">
        <ul style="list-item-style:none">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node" />
        </ul>
      </xsl:if>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You should add xml to the question.

Comment: Are you trying to hide the entire rows across (including Home, About, Service/Location and Contact columns) of the child items or just the left most column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only getting root items, you'll want to change the [`NodeSelector`](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/page/DDRMenu-reference-guide#NodeSelector_1) defined for the menu.  I believe that the shorthand value `RootChildren` will give you what you want.

Comment: <ddr:MENU ID="MENU" MenuStyle="Treeview" runat="server" NodeSelector=".,0,3"> this how I solved the issue. however, your answer helped too.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you supplied an example of the input code you would like to transform.

I assume its basically something like this:

```
<root>
  <node enabled="1" depth="1" text="Service" selected="true" breadcrumb="0"/>
  <node>
    <node>
      <node/>
    </node>
  </node>
  <node>
    <node/>
  </node>
  <node/>
</root>
```

You can skip the first template-match and those first if-element and directly match only what you're interested in. Without testing, something like this should do the trick:

```
<!-- ... -->
<!-- process only "root" elements that have at least one "node" element -->
<xsl:template match="/root[node]">
  <ul class="treeview filetree" id="{$ControlID}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node" />
  </ul>
  <!-- ... -->
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="node">
  <!-- ... -->
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without the source XML it's really hard to work out what you're trying to do here, but I'd say the main reason you're getting *all* nodes is the the template to match the `node` element is recursive and does not hide the descendants.  If you add `display:none` to the `style` attribute on the `ul` element at the end of the `node` template (or change `list-item-style` to `display`), you may get what you want.